# Removing personal options in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, backend

I'm trying to remove the personal options in wp. (keyboard shortcuts, text editing options etc.) 
I'm using this code in my functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
remove_action( 'personal_options', 'personal_options', 10, 1 );
```

The first line to remove my color scheme works, the other does not. I've tried several tutorials on this but none seem to be able to be fired. Anyone know how to remove them ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ginfuru/6417906

Comment: @TonyVincent I've already tried that, and it does not work.

Comment: See the answer in this wordpress post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/remove-personal-options-section-from-profile